# get travel time between 2 point lat , long Swift google api

Tags: ios, swift

i use google map and google place , i want to find the travel time between 2 point using lat and long , i could do that for the android part , but in swift i couldn't find anywhere the only thing i find is the Distance in KM .

this is my code where i get the Lat & long

```
func placePicker(_ viewController: GMSPlacePickerViewController, didPick place: GMSPlace) {
        // Dismiss the place picker, as it cannot dismiss itself.
        viewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        self.FullAddress = (place.formattedAddress?.components(separatedBy: ", ")
            .joined(separator: ","))!                        

        self.LatAuto = place.coordinate.latitude 
        self.LonAuto = place.coordinate.longitude 

         let location = CLLocation(latitude: self.LatAuto, longitude: self.LonAuto)

        self.fetchCityAndCountry(from: location) {
            city, country, error in
            guard let city = city, let country = country, error == nil else { return }
            print(city + ", " + country)

            self.City = city;
        }

        self.showLocation(LatSend:place.coordinate.latitude,LongSend: place.coordinate.longitude,FullAddSend:self.FullAddress)        
    }
```

2 : when using placePicker if the address was a point of no where i will get error after user select the place but i dont have this in the android version even i use google API for both

Comment: Duration? Did you mean to write distance? And how is the code relevant to your question?

Comment: Your question makes no sense. Duration? Do you mean travel time? Distance? Then you said "distention KM". What is that? Distance in KM?

Comment: @DuncanC . i edit my Question sorry for my english

Comment: How about a link to the library you're using?

Comment: @DuncanC u mean placePicker ?

Comment: I guess so. You tell us. It sounds like you actually need to use the Google directions API to get directions and travel times. See Mahesh's answer, below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use direction google api to get distance :

```
let directionURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=\(sourceLat),\(sourceLng)&destination=\(destinationLat),\(destinationLng)"

Alamofire.request(directionURL, method: .post, params: [:], encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).downloadProgress(queue: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility)){
                    progress in
                    print("Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
}
.responseJSON {
    response in
        if response.result.isSuccess {

          let JsonResponse = JSON(response.result.value!)
          let routes = JsonResponse["routes"].arrayValue
              for route in routes
              {

                 let duration = route["legs"][0]["duration"]["text"].stringValue

                  let distance = route["legs"][0]["distance"]["text"].stringValue
                }

           }
           if response.result.isFailure {
              // Show error 
           }
}
```

You will get following json :

```
{
   "geocoded_waypoints" : [
      {
         "geocoder_status" : "OK",
         "place_id" : "ChIJRVY_etDX3IARGYLVpoq7f68",
         "types" : [
            "bus_station",
            "transit_station",
            "point_of_interest",
            "establishment"
         ]
      },
      {
         "geocoder_status" : "OK",
         "partial_match" : true,
         "place_id" : "ChIJp2Mn4E2-woARQS2FILlxUzk",
         "types" : [ "route" ]
      }
   ],
   "routes" : [
      {
         "bounds" : {
            "northeast" : {
               "lat" : 34.1330949,
               "lng" : -117.9143879
            },
            "southwest" : {
               "lat" : 33.8068768,
               "lng" : -118.3527671
            }
         },
         "copyrights" : "Map data ©2016 Google",
         "legs" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "35.9 mi",
                  "value" : 57824
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "51 mins",
                  "value" : 3062
               },
               "end_address" : "Universal Studios Blvd, Los Angeles, CA 90068, USA",
               "end_location" : {
                  "lat" : 34.1330949,
                  "lng" : -118.3524442
               },
               "start_address" : "Disneyland (Harbor Blvd.), S Harbor Blvd, Anaheim, CA 92802, USA",
               "start_location" : {
                  "lat" : 33.8098177,
                  "lng" : -117.9154353
               }}],
         "summary" : "I-5 N and US-101 N",
         "warnings" : [],
         "waypoint_order" : []
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot , this look good , will try and come back to u

Comment: Please check updated ans

Comment: Use of unresolved identifier 'JsonResponse' In let routes = JsonResponse["routes"].arrayValue

Comment: @zezoalharazi please check updated ans

Comment: Now Use of unresolved identifier 'JSON'

Comment: @zezoalharazi Please install pod : pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git'

Comment: import SwiftyJSON

Comment: i add  pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.2' to my pod file , now when i do pod install all my 5 dependencies install only SwiftyJSON cant see it pod install
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using Alamofire (4.7.3)
Using AlamofireImage (3.3.1)
Using GoogleMaps (2.7.0)
Using GooglePlacePicker (2.7.0)
Using GooglePlaces (2.7.0)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 5 dependencies from the Podfile and 5 total pods installed.

Comment: ok..now use "import SwiftyJSON"  in viewcontroller

Comment: my Mistake i install SwiftyJSON to other pod project :D

Comment: thanks a lot that work great , one thing only add to the url &key=YourAPIKey

Comment: No need to add api key.